# Generalizing a simple linear-time algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to write a linear-time algorithm O(n), which given a table A[0..n-1] *(filled with ascending natural values)* checks if there is a pair A[i], A[j] which satisfies f(A[i], A[j]) = C *(C is a predefined constant)*.

Supposing that f(a,b) = a+b the algorithm will be:

```
Algo Paires(A[0..N-1], C)
in: Tab A[0..n-1] and C a constant
out : Boolean
Init indice ← 0
For i ← 0..n-1 do 
    if indice ≠ i & A[indice] + A[i] = C 
      return true
    else if i = n-1 & indice ≤ n-2 
      indice++; i ← 0;
End for
return False
```

But if:

[image]

what will be the algorithm then? any suggestions ?

Comment: It sounds like you want us to do your homework for you.

Comment: I'm just looking for some help and i think that i'm in the right place... i wrote the algo myself & now i want to generalize it but unfortenaly i cant figure out how ... i dont want you do to it for me but help me with some hints or suggestions....

Comment: It iterates n​ times on `indice`, and in each iteration it iterates n​ times on `i`.

Comment: hmmm that's true :/ any suggestion on how to change the execution time to O(n) ?

Comment: @aaz: Sorry, I voted up Mooh's comment, but now that I actually look at the solution, I see that you are correct; it is O(n²).  @Mooh: However, it can still be done simply in O(n) *(hint: one method requires two indicies, which do not both start at 0...)*

Comment: The structure is roughly correct, which is why it looks like O(n), but `i` shouldn't need to be reset to 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Suppose there is a 2D matrix whose rows and columns are sorted and you are given a number x which you need to find...

Comment: It doesn't seem like we're looking for a linear algorithm anymore because both this answer and the pseudo code in the example are quadratic. Given that, we can do calculate the answer in O(1) space right?

Comment: @efficieny: Why do you think this is quadratic?

Comment: @efficiencyIsBliss: As I mentioned above, though the pseudo-code is quadratic, it can certainly be done in linear-time (so can this).

Comment: @Moron In order to determine if there is such a pairing, don't we have to(in the worst case) compute all the entries in the 2D array?

Comment: @BlueRaja I read your comments and I agree that the pseudo-code can be done in linear time, though I can't seem to figure out how this can also be done in linear time.

Comment: @Moron My mistake, I'd forgotten the part about the array being sorted.